# Trouble with string length

Tags: java, string

So I am attempting to get my program to run through each character in my string and if it finds a number, then to print the password and exit the for loop and the while loop (did not include the while loop but it is 'while (test == 0)'). But if I enter a password without a number, it will scan the entire string and print that I need a number. For some reason, when I enter a password with a number, it works perfectly. But when I enter a password without a number, I get an error message... Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
for (int num = 0; num <= passw.length(); num++){
    if (Character.isDigit(passw.charAt(num))){
        num += 1000;
        test++;
        System.out.println(passw);
    }

    if (num >= passw.length() && num <= 1000){
        System.out.println("You need a number");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going about it the wrong way. Replace all your code with just this:

```
if (passw.matches("\\D*")) {
    System.out.println("You need a number");
}
```

This uses the regex `\D*`, which means "every character is a non-digit"

Comment: No problem. You can use regex to check for password quality in other ways too, for example ensuring it contains at least so many characters, at least one uppercase, one lowercase and one number, all in one regex (or multiple ones if you find it easier), but regex is the weapon of choice for this functionality

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int num = 0; num <= passw.length(); num++){
```

index starts from `0` not `1`

so loop should be:

```
for (int num = 0; num < passw.length(); num++){
```

Comment: That worked, but I am getting no print line saying I need to have a number... Any ideas there?

Comment: I guess If condition should be || (logical OR) rather AND.

Comment: @MitchStallings: I would give a try on Bohemian solution.

Comment: Just did. Worked like a charm... Thank you both @Bohemian and Nambari

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int num = 0; num <= passw.length(); num++){
```

will go to the character past the end of the string. Just do

```
for (int num = 0; num < passw.length(); num++){
```

Hope that helps!